# Prolog Query - Trying to understand how this result happens

Tags: prolog

So I'm trying to figure out some stuff from Prolog, but I'm not sure WHY I'm getting the result that I'm getting. Given this definition:

```
families(_, Smith, lucy, _, jeff, Smith).
```

and this query:

```
?- families(Ford, nancy, Ford, jeff, Smith, White).
```

Why is this the result?:

```
Ford = lucy,
Smith = jeff,
White = nancy.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Constants (so called atoms) start with a lower case letter. But some names start with an upper case. Put those names under quotes. Like `'Smith'`

Comment: Oh I'm not trying to get a different result or anything. This is an old example from a class where we're given the definition and the query, and we're suppose to figure out the result on paper. I typed it up to see what the result would be, but I'm just not sure why that's the result.

Comment: It's not that it's failing... the 'Ford = lucy, Smith = jeff, White = nancy.' is the result. I typed it all into swipl to see the result, but I'm not sure why it's coming up with that.

Comment: There must be a typo in your Question.  As stated your query would force `Smith` to unify with both `nancy` and `jeff`, which is impossible.

Comment: Not sure. I'm using 

( from file ) families( _, Smith, lucy, _, jeff, Smith ).
?- families( Ford, nancy, Ford, jeff, Smith, White ).
Ford = lucy,
Smith = jeff,
White = nancy.

Comment: @hardmath I too failed on this for a minute, but variables in predicates [are renamed on use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20198876/849891). :) (... I even upvoted your comment there) :)

Comment: @WillNess: Excellent point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A note: no need to leave spaces after the opening and before the closing parenthesis. Also, if this is homework, you should say so.)

The definition of `families/6`,

```
families(_, Smith, lucy, _, jeff, Smith).
```

says:

1. Ignore first argument and fourth argument (the underscores);
2. Unify the second and the last argument (both arguments referred to by the same variable name, *Smith*);
3. Unify the third argument with the atom `lucy`;
4. Unify the fifth argument with the atom `jeff`.

Now your query,

```
?- families(Ford, nancy, Ford, jeff, Smith, White).
```

asks:

- Can you unify the first and third argument with the same variable, *Ford*?

  - yes, you can, and now `Ford = lucy` (from 3. in the definition).
- Can the second argument be the atom `nancy`?

  - yes, and `White = nancy` (from 2. in the definition)
- Can the fourth argument be the atom `jeff`?

  - yes, but this doesn't have any effect (from 1. in the definition)
- Can you unify the fifth argument with the variable *Smith*?

  - yes, and `Smith = jeff` (from 4. in the definition).

This should be clear now, assuming you know how unification works. Important is that variable names in the definition and the query are in different contexts and having the same name means nothing (as in *Smith* in positions 2 and 6 in the definition and *Smith* in position 5 in the query).

Altogether this is a convoluted example that uses variable and atom names in an attempt to confuse the human reader. It forces you to pay attention though and can be useful as an example of bad programming style.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. And it's not homework, just an example from an exam review :)

Answer (score 2):

As a visual aid to [the answer by Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20186642/849891), we can write the predicate and the query one beside the other,

```
   families( _   , Smith, lucy, _   , jeff , Smith).
?- families( Ford, nancy, Ford, jeff, Smith, White).
```

Now, *`Smith`* in the definition and *`Smith`* in the query are *not* the same! Each predicate has its own *"namespace"* in effect, because predicate's variables are renamed on predicate's use. So we actually have here

```
   families( _   , A    , lucy, _   , jeff , A    ).
?- families( Ford, nancy, Ford, jeff, Smith, White).
```

which matches, producing the substitution

```
_=Ford, A=nancy, lucy=Ford, _=jeff, jeff=Smith, A=White.
```

i.e.

```
Ford=lucy, Smith=jeff, White=nancy.
```

The last one is the consequence of *`White=A`* and *`A=nancy`*. *`A`* itself isn't reported because it is not one of the query's logical variables.