# Simple query in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this statement:

```
friends(Nancy,richard,_,Nancy,michael)
```

And this query:

```
friends(simon, Nancy, Friend, Richard, Friend).
```

The result I get is:

```
Nancy = richard
Friend = Michael
Richard = Simon
```

Can anyone explain to me how these results get generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule contains a variable, `Nancy`:

```
   friends(  Nancy,  richard,       _,    Nancy,  michael).
```

when a rule is used, its variables get renamed:

```
   friends(      A,  richard,       _,        A,  michael).
?- friends(  simon,    Nancy,  Friend,  Richard,   Friend).
```

Thus we get `A=simon, richard=Nancy, _=Friend, A=Richard, michael=Friend`.

Only the variables present in the query are reported:

```
Richard=simon, Nancy=richard, Friend=michael.
```

as you can see, you've typos in your results.

see also: [Prolog Query - Trying to understand how this result happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184656/prolog-query-trying-to-understand-how-this-result-happens/20198876#20198876)